# Get video id from Vimeo url

Tags: javascript, regex, vimeo

I'm trying to find the best regexp to fetch vimeo video id from URL.

**Example urls :**

```
https://vimeo.com/11111111
http://vimeo.com/11111111
https://www.vimeo.com/11111111
http://www.vimeo.com/11111111
https://vimeo.com/channels/11111111
http://vimeo.com/channels/11111111
https://vimeo.com/groups/name/videos/11111111
http://vimeo.com/groups/name/videos/11111111
https://vimeo.com/album/2222222/video/11111111
http://vimeo.com/album/2222222/video/11111111
https://vimeo.com/11111111?param=test
http://vimeo.com/11111111?param=test
```

My current regexp which doesn't work:

```
/http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/
```

**Playground & Test here :** http://jsbin.com/asuqic/1/edit?javascript,live

Comment: you could use `url.split('/').slice(-1)[0].split('?')[0]`, or is regex a requirement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since 2016. And **@Martin Ender** said `no longer up to date`

---

So here is a **API solution :** *(without regexp but API caller and safe!)*

**jQuery :**

```
function GetVimeoIDbyUrl(url) {
  var id = false;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url='+url,
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {
      if(response.video_id) {
        id = response.video_id;
      }
    }
  });
  return id;
}
```

**Minify :**

```
function GetVimeoIDbyUrl(e){var i=!1;return $.ajax({url:"https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url="+e,async:!1,success:function(e){e.video_id&&(i=e.video_id)}}),i}
```

---

**Pure/Native JS :** *(IE9+ & Modern browsers)*

```
function GetVimeoIDbyUrl(url) {
  var id = false;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url='+url , false);
  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      if(response.video_id) {
        id = response.video_id;
      }
    }
  };
  request.send();
  return id;
}
```

**Minify :**

```
function GetVimeoIDbyUrl(e){var t=!1,o=new XMLHttpRequest;return o.open("GET","https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url="+e,!1),o.onload=function(){if(o.status>=200&&o.status<400){var e=JSON.parse(o.responseText);e.video_id&&(t=e.video_id)}},o.send(),t}
```

---

**Demo :** https://jsbin.com/mevejoxudo/1/edit?js,output

**Some type of url doesn't support ? :** https://vimeo.com/help/contact#tech-api *( Tell them, dont tell me hehe :D )*

Answer (score 44):

**Update:** I notice that this answer is getting some attention every now and then (through votes or comments). **The answer is more than two years old**, and likely the URL types supported are no longer up to date. I will not actively maintain this regex - it is merely intended as an answer to the question and hence only takes care of the formats listed there. Use this at your own risk, or - even better - use it merely as a starting point to develop your own regex based on an up-to-date and comprehensive list of URL formats.

See @l2aelba's answer for API solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/37695721/622813

---

This would be the full regex, which also ensures that the format is correct:

```
/https?:\/\/(?:www\.|player\.)?vimeo.com\/(?:channels\/(?:\w+\/)?|groups\/([^\/]*)\/videos\/|album\/(\d+)\/video\/|video\/|)(\d+)(?:$|\/|\?)/
```

You can now retrieve the group name in capturing group `1` (if present), the album ID in capturing group `2` (if present) and the video ID in capturing group `3` (always).

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/asuqic/184/edit?javascript,live)

Comment: some error ? `Line 1: vimeo_Reg = /https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?vimeo.com\/(?:channels\/|groups\/[^\/]*\/videos\/|album\/\d+\/video\/|)(\d+)($|\/|?)/; --- Unescaped '?'.`

Comment: @l2aelba sorry, copy paste mistake. copy the code from my answer into the demo.

Comment: can you edit your demo link to `jsbin.com/asuqic/11/edit?javascript,live` ? i think your answer will be accepted :D

Comment: @l2aelba then I guess I had the wrong link in my answer again :D ... anyway, all settled now ;)

Comment: I came across a link that goes vimeo.com/channels/channelname/video_id (probably because this thread is a bit old) which isn't covered by your result. I changed it up to 
/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?vimeo.com\/(?:channels\/\w*\/*|groups\/([^\/]*)\/videos\/|album\/(\d+)\/video\/|)(\d+)(?:$|\/|\?)/;

But then I get the wrong result for "http://www.vimeo.com/11111111".
Maybe you can see right away what I am doing wrong haha

Comment: @Aurelin I think you wanted `channels\/(?:\w+\/)?` in order to ensure that there is another `/` after the channel name parameter. I'll edit the post, and finally fix that typo.

Comment: Ah yes thank you!
What is the ?: for, if you don't mind explaining?

Comment: @Aurelin [it suppresses capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: Added one more case "https://vimeo.com/ondemand/santaquest/114026446" 
Live: http://jsbin.com/taxugalalu/1/

Comment: I'm not expert in javascript regex and I can't support this kind of urls

"http://vimeo.com/user18322218/review/66338120/7678a41439" can you handle it?

Comment: Is there such a thing for youtube?

Comment: It would be nice to retrieve [playback starting time](https://vimeo.com/help/faq/sharing-videos/share-features#can-i-link-viewers-to-a-specific-part-of-my-video) with a capturing group 4.  For instance https://vimeo.com/11111111#t=1m2s.

Answer (score 4):

```
var r = /(videos|video|channels|\.com)\/([\d]+)/,
    a = "https://vimeo.com/album/2222222/video/11111111";

console.log(a.match(r)[2]); // 11111111;
```

http://jsbin.com/asuqic/7/edit

Answer (score 3):

The following regex will return the id on group 1 for those who only want to retrieve this information. It works with all the example URLs given in the question.
It also works without `http://` and `https://`.
It also works with URLs like `player.vimeo.com/...`

```
/^.*(?:vimeo.com)\\/(?:channels\\/|groups\\/[^\\/]*\\/videos\\/|album\\/\\d+\\/video\\/|video\\/|)(\\d+)(?:$|\\/|\\?)/
```

Comment: Here is the unescaped version + added support for http://vimeo.com/channels/channelname/1111111111: `/^.*(?:vimeo.com)\/(?:channels\/|channels\/\w+\/|groups\/[^\/]*\/videos\/|album\/\d+\/video\/|video\/|)(\d+)(?:$|\/|\?)/`

Answer (score 0):

For php, below code works for following urls

i.e. :

```
http://vimeo.com/88888888
http://player.vimeo.com/video/88888888
http://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/88888888
http://vimeo.com/groups/groupsname/88888888
```

PHP Code :

```
    $vimeoUrl = 'http://vimeo.com/channels/channelsName/11111111';
    $fetchVimeoIdArr = explode('/', $vimeoUrl);
    $idCounter = count($fetchVimeoIdArr) - 1;
    $vimeoId = $fetchVimeoIdArr[$idCounter];
```

Comment: it will return  : 11111111?param=test